# Style a menu inside a specific block

Tags: routes, blocks, theming

I've created one menu to be placed on the left column and with context it will be repeated on the footer too.
The difference is that the footer menu has to be already expanded and show all the child.

I can use  this code below to make it as expanded

```
function mytheme_menu_link_alter(&$item, $menu) {
    if($item['menu_name'] == 'menu-about-us')
    {
        $item['expanded'] = 1;
    }
}
```

How do I targer the menu in the footer?
How should I use the function `mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables)` ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your after is the following...

```
context_active_contexts()
```

http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/context_active_contexts/7

Example:

```
if (module_exists('context')) {
    $active_contexts = array_keys(context_active_contexts());
    if (in_array('SOMETHING', $active_contexts)) {
       //...
    } 
}
```

Comment: what's "something" in this case?

Comment: What are you getting back from $active_contexts?

Comment: Sorry, may you do an example of it please?

Comment: Put the code above in mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) then see what you get when you var_dump($active_contexts).

Comment: Thanks Alex, but it's much easier with [Menu Block][1].
Thanks anyway for your help


  [1]: http://drupal.org/project/menu_block